# A special afterlife for suicides

Tags: story-identification

I tried to google this but all I saw were many religious topics.

The story was set in a place called Sundownia. It was a special afterlife for suicides. Civilization was completely normal. You could go to a bar and drink but you would never get drunk.

Most people didn't know they were dead but a few did and they had super powers because they knew they were dead.

The people who knew they were dead looked for each other and chose up sides to fight each other because they were already dead and weren't going to die. There was just nothing else to do.

The people who didn't know they were dead never noticed that the others could fly or morph into a motor cycle.

This could have been a graphic novel. This post makes me kind of ashamed of myself. I have always been a voracious reader but I never retain the meta like authors or in this case even the media used.

Comment: Is this a book? A comic series? A TV series? Please apply the appropriate tag by [edit]ing and see if you can add any more [details](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info).

Comment: sounds a bit like 'What Dreams May Come' by Matheson - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_Dreams_May_Come

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it. The film was called *[Wristcutters: A love story](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0477139/)* and the graphic novel was called *[Pizzeria Kamikaze](http://www.bookslut.com/fiction/2007_02_010612.php)*. They're both based off of the short story, "[Kneller's Happy Campers](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6324467-kneller-s-happy-campers)"

> Kneller's Happy Campers is a strange, dark but funny tale set in a world very much like our own but it's an afterlife populated by people who have killed themselves - many of them are young, and most of them bear the marks of their death... bullet wounds, broken necks...(those who have over-dosed are known as 'Juliets').
>
> When Mordy, our hero, discovers that his girlfriend from his life before has also 'offed' herself, he sets out to find her, and so follows a strange adventure...
>
> Full of the weird and wonderful characters, and the slightly surreal twist of events that we've come to expect from Etgar Keret, this novella is full of humour and comic flashes, but it is also wistful, longing for a better world and perfect love.

I chose another answer because I started wondering if I just rememberimagined the whole thing.

But I got a treat.  Dark humor, happy ending. And I will always worry about losing things under the seats of my car.

Comment: You can _change_ your accepted answer to this one. Self-answering is totally fine.

Comment: Since the other answer is not the story you remembered and this is, you should change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 10):

Could be [**What Dreams May Come**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_Dreams_May_Come) by Richard Matheson:

> 'What Dreams May Come' is a 1978 novel by Richard Matheson. The plot
>   centers on Chris, a man who dies then goes to Heaven, but descends
>   into Hell to rescue his wife.

*Suicide:*

> Albert, who is as shocked as Chris, explains that by committing
>   suicide Ann has placed her spirit in the "lower realm" from
>   Summerland, and that she will stay there for twenty-four years — her
>   intended life span. Albert insists that Ann's condition is not
>   "punishment" but "law" - a natural consequence of committing suicide.

*Joy after awareness of death: (in the film, Chris finds he can fly):*

> Summerland is practically endless and takes the form of the
>   inhabitants' wishes and desires.

*Violence in a separated area:*

> They eventually reach a place occupied by people who were violent
>   criminals while alive. Chris witnesses a series of dreadful sights and
>   is gruesomely attacked by a mob

[image: Book cover]

Was also a film starring Robin Williams - now increasingly sad in light of his own suicide

[image: Film poster]

Comment: yeah, this is probably what I was thinking. I think my memory embellished.  Sundownia kind of sounds like "The whole Year Inn"